# Get Current value of a Firebase Node? (Using AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Trying to update the information in a node by adding an amount to the *current* value.  I can't find a way to reference the current value so I can add my value.  How can you call the current value?

```
.update({total: "current-value?" + $scope.user.amount}).then(function() {       
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to add? Updating values in a realtime database is tricky because you can run into race conditions. If you aren't using transactions or lists you probably won't get the value you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to add a number to a number, so the current value might be 0 or 18 etc. It looks like I can call the current value with a function and then use transaction to add a number. I was just wondering if there was a variable that would call the current value.

Comment: ` "current-value?" + $scope.user.amount` creates the string `current-value?n` where `n` is the amount; it does not perform an arithmetic addition. Your question is a little on the lean side. Perhaps add some real code we can run and see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you might not be able to pull the current value of a node without using a function, that is what I did:

```
snap.ref().child('gold/total').transaction(function(currentVal) {
        return (currentVal || 0) + $scope.user.amount;
     });
```

The current value of the node is captured with "currentVal", and then it can be passed along so that the addition can be performed.